# ES6 transpile the "species pattern" for old browsers

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was reading about the  [species pattern](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#sec_species-pattern)

Having the following code

```
 class MyArray1 extends Array {
    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Array;
    }
}
```

We can make for methods like **slice** to return an instance of Array.

So if I validate `(new MyArray1).slice() instanceof MyArray1` will be **false**.

All good till now.

But what if I want to transpile this code, let's say with *babeljs*; as far as I know it will not work for older browsers that does not have the new implementation of the [slice](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice) method were it states

> Let A be ArraySpeciesCreate(O, count).

If that is true, so I can not transpile this new feature, my question is:

Are there any other solutions(polyfills, etc)? Or this feature can not be used on older browsers even if we transpile the code?

Comment: Yes, you could use a polyfill that overwrites all array methods with species-aware ones. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: the author of that book gives us a reason why "As an example, consider a subclass SortedArray of Array...."

Comment: Ah, so it's just for the learning experience not a real world use case.

Comment: my question? yes, but the pattern, I think not...